# Do some gases have short range order?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, gas, amorphous-solids

In the book "Essentials of Materials Science and Engineering" (Askeland, Fulay), it appears the following figure:

[image: Taken from the book Essentials of Materials Science]

We can read in the figure's description, subsection (b,c), that vapor and nitrogen gas have short range order. Yet in the following web page: https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Long-Range+and+Short-Range+Order, which references a Soviet Encyclopaedia, it reads: "both long range and short range order are absent in the ideal gas". I tend to agree with this last statement, but I am not sure. Also, in the following reference (https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/short-range-order), one can read: "A completely structurally disordered material (e.g. a gas) has a uniform probability of finding neighboring atoms at all possible distances (larger than twice the atomic radius), leading to a featureless g(r)."
Do some gases have short range order, or don't they?
I really like Askeland's book, but if this is a mistake, it seems quite severe.
Any help settling this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The key word is “ideal”. Real gases are not ideal gases.

Comment: "Short" is also ambiguous, potentially referring to either intermolecular or intramolecular order. When we idealize water vapor as an ideal gas, we ignore the regular geometry of the hydrogen and oxygen molecule and consider it to be a point—with no ordering around it.

Comment: @Chemomechanics There is no room for ambiguity. Long-range or short-range order in the Physics of condensed matter always refers to the intermolecular space correlations. The intra-molecular structure is never taken into account.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Thank you for your answer. What you say is what I was thinking. Calling short range order the intramolecular order of a gas molecule does not make for a sensible definition, at least for me. But then again, the definition of short range order talks about the probability of finding atoms in the near vecinity of another atom, not molecules: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/short-range-order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When faced with terminology-related problems, a general warning is to double-check the conventions in the specific area of research.

In Condensed Matter Physics, short-, intermediate-, or long-range order refers to correlations over the distances of the first neighbors, a few shells of neighbors, or extending over the whole sample size.
Usually, such correlations are measured by the radial behavior of the pair correlation function.

Intra-molecular correlations in molecular systems are usually excluded by
considerations about the short-range order, at least in the phases where molecules are stable.

The prototype of a system without any spatial order is the perfect gas. Its radial correlation function is everywhere zero, or its radial distribution function is equal to $1$ at all distances. Such value encodes that in a perfect gas, a second atom/molecule can be found with the same probability at every distance from a given atom/molecule.

Such theoretical behavior is unphysical for real atoms/molecules that show, even at the highest temperature, an almost negligible probability of finding two molecules, one on top of the other (a huge repulsion appears when two molecules are put too close to each other. Still, such an *exclusion hole* in the radial distribution function is not considered a *short-range order*. The fingerprint of the short-range order is a visible increase in the probability of finding a pair of molecules at distances corresponding to the first neighbors over the random value of $1$. Typically, this is the situation of a dense gas or a liquid at a very high temperature.

When the temperature decreases, correlations increase, and spatial order over more than the scale of the first neighbors is visible,

As an illustration, using a reliable semiquantitative theory (hyper-netted chain approximation), I have evaluated the radial distribution functions for three states of a gas/liquid of Lennard-Jones atoms. Distances are in units of $\sigma$.[image: radial distribution functions for three states of a gas/liquid of Lennard-Jones atoms.].

The reduced density $\rho^*=\rho \sigma^3=0.001$ and $T^*=100$ (top panel) corresponds to a dilute gas at a very high temperature (about a factor 80 above the critical point). A part the exclusion hole due to the harsh repulsion at short range, there is no spatial structure and no short-range order.

The intermediate panel corresponds to a density $\rho^*=\rho \sigma^3=0.84$ close to the triple point density but at a very high temperature (the same as in the top panel). Here some short-range order appears.

The lower panel corresponds to density and temperature close to the triple point values. Here additional peaks beyond the first neighbor peak signal an intermediate range order extending beyond the first shell of neighbors.

Notice that such behavior is typical and not restricted to Lennard-Jones systems.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this is way beyond what I expected. If I understood you correctly, the confusion comes then from what the author defines as neighbour. For the author, 2 atoms of the same molecular gas are neighbours, whereas what you are saying is that the neighbours are the molecules and not the atoms.
Now, in amorphous SiO2, is it not the case that what physicists consider neighbours are the Si and O atoms, and not the SiO2 molecules? What is the criteria for deciding when to analyze atomic neighbourhood  vs molecular neighbourhood?
Thank you very much for your insight

Comment: Oh, is it the fact that SiO2 molecules are not stable but N2 or H2O molecules are?
For example in this picture https://www.e-education.psu.edu/matse81/node/2154 
Si atoms seem to be bounded to 3 oxygen atoms, not 2, as the formula would imply.

Comment: @DavidEspinoza Yes, a distinction between intra- and inter-molecular correlations requires a previous analysis of the stability of molecules in condensed phases. In practice, this is possible only in the condensed phases where stable molecules can be clearly identified. At normal conditions, SiO$_2$ molecules lose their individual character to build a tetrahedral network.

Comment: This answer might be a touch on the technical side, but I do think you did a nice job of illustrating just how technical the definitions of different terms can be, especially with regard to differences in disciplines.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe the author has made a mistake, but perhaps could have been slightly clearer. As a commenter has already noted, the key word in your second citation is "ideal." By definition, an ideal gas is one which does not have any interactions between separate gas molecules. In the limit of infinite dilution, all gases are necessarily ideal. But as you start to increase the pressure of gases they will all break ideality to differing degrees based on the volumetric and quantum mechanical nature (i.e. bonding capabilities) of the specific particles. This image actually does quite a nice job of showing the sort of continuum of types of ordering in matter. Short range ordering can be seen as something of an intermediate behavior between true bonding between separate particles-which would mean you have an entirely new gas to deal with-and the complete lack of interaction seen in an ideal gas. For instance, water vapor would necessarily include sporadic hydrogen bonding interactions between neighboring water molecules due to the intrinsic dipole moment of each molecule.

Comment: I dont think it has to do with the definition of ideal gas. This is another quote from the same page of Askeland's book:"Each water molecule in steam has a short-range order due to the covalent bonds between the hydrogen and oxygen atoms; that is, each oxygen atom is joined to two hydrogen atoms, forming an angle of 104.5 between the bonds. However, the water molecules in steam have no special arrangement with respect to each other’s position." So it is assuming an ideal gas. He's calling short range order the internal order of the molecule, which for me does not make for a sensible definition

Comment: Ah, I suppose I may have misinterpreted the meaning of order here. In statistical mechanics we typically refer to ordering with respect to the distinct species, not their constituent atoms. But I can also see how that terminology could be used.

Answer (score 1):

I think this reference, along with @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 's answer completely settles the issue.
Reference: "The Liquid and Supercritical Fluid States of Matter"

[image]